# Where does $\chi_{[0,k]}(x)$ converge point wise when $k\rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

When $k\rightarrow \infty$ does it hold that $\chi_{[0,k]} \rightarrow 1$ point wise? Can we conclude from this that $\int |f_k-f|=\int |\chi_{[0,k]}-1|>0$?

Comment: You've mixed up $n$ with $k.$

Comment: Alright I fixed it.

Comment: The integrals you write down are undefined/do not converge, so asking whether they are equal or positive doesn't immediately make sense.

Comment: It would someone not familiar with this context.  Define $\chi_{[0,k]}$.

Comment: $\chi_{[0,k]} \to \chi_{[0,+\infty)}$ pointwise.  This is not $1$ everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The pointwise convergence $\chi_{[0,k]} \rightarrow 1$ follows pretty easily by definition. However, notice that for each $k \in \mathbb{R}_+$, the integral $$\int |\chi_{[0,k]}(x) - 1|\, dx = \int_{x\geq k} 1\,dx = \infty,$$ thus it diverges.